# Credential prompts shows up though I embedded in the script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell script which runs perfectly when I open Windows PowerShell ISE and execute it. This script has username and password embedded in it. No prompts rise asking for password when I execute this.

```
$encrypted = Get-Content E:\servers\Disk Space Monitoring\password.txt |ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("\svc_user", $encrypted)
New-PSDrive -Name TARGET -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\**.**.***.**\Dev\VI_ONE\Backups\TM1 10.2" -Credential $credential
New-PSDrive -Name SOURCE -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "**.**.***.**\servers" -Credential $credential
```

But when I execute the same script by using mouse *right-click → Run with Powershell*, two prompts pops up (for each PSDrive respectively) asking for user name and password.

The same happens when I call the PowerShell script via batch script.

How to avoid this prompt?

FYI, I have stored the password as an encrypted file. Please ignore to which directory I'm moving to as I have *ed them.

Comment: ISE handles variables differently than the default powershell.
If you add echo statements for the variables do they write out?

Comment: For one thing your script has a path with spaces that is not in quotes, so it should throw an error that `Get-Content` cannot find a positional parameter to accept the value "Space". Also, was `password.txt` created on the same computer with the same user account?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the password was encrpted for the same account but using another machine. Could that really be a cause?

Comment: Yes. The encryption is tied to both user account and machine, making exported secure strings non-portable.

Comment: I don't have WRITE access to this machine, that is the reason I moved the password file using another account.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, you were right. I'm not able to use the DEV machine encrypted file in PROD machine. I tried executing the code with a password file encrypted in PROD environment and it ran as expected. So password need to be encrypted in individual machines separately and will not work if copy pasted over machine to machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password files can be copied from servers to servers. It is not mandatory that it should be encrypted in individual servers.
The above condition is needed only if you encrypt the file without a key.
If you use a key and encrypt the file, then it can be shared across and used.

```
$encrypted = Get-Content E:\tm1servers\Disk_Space_Monitoring\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain.com\svc-tm1q", $encrypted)
```

while encrypting the file use the same key **-Key (1..16)**